# Initiating Soundcloud for practice page

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I've registered a practice app for soundcloud in order to get a client id. My app doesn't have an official site because I don't want to register a domain. I'm just trying to learn how to use soundcloud using a .html and .js file. I've followed the [API tutorials exactly](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript), but nothing happens whenever I try to use soundcloud. I initialized SC using my client ID, and have imported JQuery and everything I need to. Thanks for the help

my html file (practice.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
        <script src= "script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>   
        <div id="player"></div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

my .js file (script.js):

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'the client id they gave me...'
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    SC.get('/tracks/293', function(track) {
        SC.oEmbed(track.permalink_url, document.getElementById('player'));
    });
});
```

Again, nothing happens when I load the page...

Comment: Hi Greg, one suggestion. Please always properly indent your code. You'd be surprised at how many errors or hard-to-find bugs are simply the result of difficult-to-read code. Good luck! :)

Comment: Also, did you paste this code from your files or type by hand? You're missing a `>` on your third script tag, which may or may not be missing in your actual code.

Comment: ok thanks, and that '>' is in my code as of now. I saw somewhere where I might need to use a web server to to run this instead of just running it off my file system. So that might be the problem

Comment: Most likely, yes. A lot of times pages must be loaded using http in order to run effectively. Check out Mampp, LAMPP, or XAMPP for quick and easy ways to get setup with a local Apache server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the full url for the SoundCloud JavaScript SDK (missing `http:`):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
        <script src= "script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>   
        <div id="player"></div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

You should be able to run this locally within your browser as SoundCloud supports Cross Origin Resource Sharing headers, removing the restriction on XSS: [Of CORS We Do](http://backstage.soundcloud.com/2010/08/of-cors-we-do/)